# Joining 2 separate excel based 1 condition with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have these two frames

df1

| birthdate | ceremony_number |
| --- | --- |
| 9/30/1895 | 1st |
| 7/23/1884 | 1st |
| 3/29/1889 | 2nd |
| 4/10/1868 | 3rd |
| 4/8/1892 | 2nd |

df2

| index | dates |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1929-05-16 |
| 2 | 1930-04-03 |
| 3 | 1930-11-05 |

I thing is combine both based on the ceremony_number column that its at df1. I mean, if df1['ceremony_number'] matchs with df2['index'] then grab df2['dates'] and add it to new column df1['date_oscar']. The new column should look like this

df1

| birthdate | date_oscar |
| --- | --- |
| 1895-09-30 | 1929-05-16 |
| 1884-07-23 | 1929-05-16 |
| 1889-03-29 | 1930-04-03 |
| 1868-04-10 | 1930-11-05 |
| 1892-8-4 | 1930-04-03 |

I've been trying to do this but it is not working

```
award_year = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    award_year.append(df1[(row['ceremony_number'] == df2['index'])])
df1['date_oscar'] = award_year
```

And this is the error:

```
Empty DataFrame Columns: [index, fechas] Index...
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `map` `ceremony_number` after extracting digits to `df2` `index`:

```
df1['birthdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['birthdate'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
df2['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['dates'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

num = df1['ceremony_number'].str.extract('^(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int)
df1['date_oscar'] = num.map(df2['dates'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
   birthdate ceremony_number date_oscar
0 1895-09-30             1st 1929-05-16
1 1884-07-23             1st 1929-05-16
2 1889-03-29             2nd 1930-04-03
3 1868-04-10             3rd 1930-11-05
4 1892-04-08             2nd 1930-04-03
```

Minimal Working Example

```
data1 = {'birthdate': {0: '9/30/1895', 1: '7/23/1884', 2: '3/29/1889',
                       3: '4/10/1868', 4: '4/8/1892'},
         'ceremony_number': {0: '1st', 1: '1st', 2: '2nd', 3: '3rd', 4: '2nd'}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'dates': {1: '1929-05-16', 2: '1930-04-03', 3: '1930-11-05'}}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# df1
   birthdate ceremony_number
0  9/30/1895             1st
1  7/23/1884             1st
2  3/29/1889             2nd
3  4/10/1868             3rd
4   4/8/1892             2nd

# df2
        dates
1  1929-05-16
2  1930-04-03
3  1930-11-05
```

Comment: Holy Moses! Thank you